# How to add soap ws addressing header in response

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, action

I am new to SOAP WS, I was trying to add a header to soap response using spring-boot, but unable to do, can anyone help to obtain the below result. showing below header and response I excepting

Request:

```
       <soap:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">@@@</Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:a648da6e-863c-42e0-9770-d1d83209cbe7</MessageID>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">  @@@@@@  </To>
    <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
    </ReplyTo>
</soap:Header>
```

Response:

```
    <soap:Header>
    <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> @@@ </Action>
    <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:d719f79e-b8a6-4c1b-a257-dfa7917d88e6</MessageID>
    <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</To>
    <RelatesTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">urn:uuid:a648da6e-863c-42e0-9770-d1d83209cbe7</RelatesTo>
</soap:Header>
```